# How can I convert so many "if" to "for"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing my homework using Python's dictionary.

I find that I can't write index for Dictionary because I'm a beginner about Python.

But I don't like this lot of "if" and "else".

How can you turn this into "for"?

This is the code for personality type test similar to MBTI.

It is necessary to compare the values of the first key and the second key, but it is not necessary to compare the values of the second key and the third key.

I want this kind of comparison. "if myDict[currentKey] > myDict[nextKey]:"

here's my code.

```
myDict={"R":0,"T":2,"C":3,"F":5,"J":2,"M":1,"A":4,"N":6}

    if myDict["R"] >= myDict["T"]: #
        myString += "R"
    else:
        myString += "T"
    if myDict["C"] >= myDict["F"]:
        myString += "C"
    else:
        myString += "F"
    if myDict["J"] >= myDict["M"]:
        myString += "J"
    else:
        myString += "M"
    if myDict["A"] >= myDict["N"]:
        myString += "A"
    else:
        myString += "N"


print(myString)
```

I want this kind of comparison. "if myDict[currentKey] > myDict[nextKey]:"

Comment: You compare R to T, but then you jump to comparing C to F without first comparing T to C. Is this intended?

Comment: As you are doing things by order, you probably should use a list, not a dict.

Comment: Make a list of the pairs you want to test & loop over them.

Comment: It looks like you're relying on dictionary ordering. Whilst that's guaranteed from >3.7, it really hints at a deeper problem.

Comment: Were you given the original logic or did you write it yourself? It'd be helpful to know what specification you wrote it to, instead of needing to guess at the spec from the logic that resulted.

Comment: Your approach looks promising. Do you want to compare all permutations of keys or just those in a sequence? What values should `currentKey` and `nextKey` have?

Comment: Sembei Norimaki // Yes, that's what I meant.
It is necessary to compare the first key and the second key.
No comparison between the second key and the third key is required.

Comment: If you want `>`, why do you use `>=`?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over your arbitrarily chosen pairs of keys, and select the key corresponding the greater value `myDict` using a custom key lookup function passed to [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
myDict = {"R": 0, "T": 2, "C": 3, "F": 5, "J": 2, "M": 1, "A": 4, "N": 6}
myString = ""

pairs = [("R", "T"), ("C", "F"), ("J", "M"), ("A", "N")]

for left, right in pairs:
    myString += max(left, right, key=myDict.get)

print(myString)
```

outputs

```
TFJN
```

Comment: @chepner I think I agree that it's safe enough here. Generally I'd prefer "hard" errors to soft ones. If I made a typo somewhere in the key pairs, I'd rather get an expressive `KeyError` than a "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str"

Answer (score 0):

On way of doing it is iterating over the dictionary elements by index:

However as @roganjosh mentioned this relies on dictionary ordering which is not guaranteed for versions < 3.7

Depending on you application a list of tuples might be a better option

```
myData = [("R", 0),(..),...]
```

But if you want to be able to access values given a key and take advantage of hashing, keep it as a dict.

```
# notice the -1, since we are comparing to the next element, 
# we can only iterate until the penultimate one.
for i in range(len(myDict.keys())-1):
    # then you can compare the current element with the next one and 
    # append the greater key to myString
    if myDict.keys()[i] >= myDict.keys()[i+1]
        myString += myDict.keys()[i]  
    else: 
        myString += myDict.keys()[i+1]
```

Comment: This is actually the answer I wanted.
However, "return value" of "keys() method" could only be converted to "list" to use "index".
Nevertheless, it was very helpful.
Of course, my approach seems fundamentally wrong, but I will use this method this time.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `iter()` over the `items()` of you dictionary so as to process those items two at a time.

```py
myDict={"R":0,"T":2,"C":3,"F":5,"J":2,"M":1,"A":4,"N":6}

my_dict_iter = iter(myDict.items())
myString = ""
for key1, value1 in my_dict_iter:
    key2, value2 = next(my_dict_iter)
    myString += key1 if value1 >= value2 else key2

print(myString)
```

That should give you:

```
TFJN
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will loop over the keys in the dictionary and uses the comparison that you want. Keep in mind that this may not be the optimal solution. So if you don't have to use a dictionary and loop the way you originally wanted to, consider using one of the other solutions.

```
myDict = {"R":0,"T":2,"C":3,"F":5,"J":2,"M":1,"A":4,"N":6}
keys = list(myDict.keys())

myString = ""
for i in range(0, len(keys), 2):
    currentKey = keys[i]
    nextKey = keys[i + 1]

    if myDict[currentKey] >= myDict[nextKey]:
        myString += currentKey
    else:
        myString += nextKey

print(myString)
```